# Displaying rich text box formats in reportviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, reportviewer

I have a rich text box named `rtb` whose data are inserted in a SQL table like this:

```cs
private void insertdata(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    string name = nameofstudent.Text;
    string father = fatherofstudent.Text;
               
    string id = stud_id.Text;
    string gender;
    if (male.IsChecked == true)
    {
        gender = "M";
    }
    else
        gender = "F";
    
    var richTextBoxContent = new TextRange(this.rtb.Document.ContentStart, this.rtb.Document.ContentEnd);

    string Place = richTextBoxContent.Text;

    connect();
    con.Open();

    string saved = "insert into student_details (Student_ID,Student_Name,Father_Name,Gender,Address)values('" 
    + id + "', '" + name + "','" + father + "','" + gender + "','" + Place + "')";
               
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(saved, con);
                                    
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("record is added");
}
```

to change the format of the rich text field, I have a button which will change any selected word to bold.

```cs
private void changefont(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextSelection text = rtb.Selection;
    if (!text.IsEmpty)
    {
        text.ApplyPropertyValue(RichTextBox.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
    }
    else
    {
        text.ApplyPropertyValue(RichTextBox.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Normal);
    }     
}
```

I have a button that generates the report in report viewer.

```cs
private void reportviewing(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
    connect();
    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from student_details", con);

    DataTable newtab = new DataTable();
    adp.Fill(newtab);
    reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1";

    reportDataSource.Value = newtab;
    studentreport.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\\Users\\Alice Luver\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\STDNT\\STDNT\\studentsreport.rdlc";

    studentreport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

    studentreport.LocalReport.Refresh();
    studentreport.RefreshReport();
}
```

This also works.

My problem is that I am unable to save the formats.

For example, I want to save a rich text field as: "Hi I am **alice**"

It is being saved and displayed as: "Hi I am alice" without the bold font.

How can I solve this? Thank you

Comment: You have to save this meta information too.You are currently extracting only the plain text from the `RichTextBox` and discarding the text attributes. The information whether text is rendered bold is stored in the container `TextElement` e.g. `Run` or `Span`. Either extract the complete elements of the `FlowDocument` or create a index you can use to convert plain text back to rich text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextRange.Save` and `TextRange.Load` to save/load formatted content from the `FlowDocument`. Saving the content as RTF preserves the formatting information.

```
private async Task SaveAndLoadRtfDocumentExampleAsync()
{
  // Select some text
  var textRange = new TextRange(this.RichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, this.RichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);

  // Convert the FlowDocument selection to a RTF string
  string rtfText;
  using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    textRange.Save(outputStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    outputStream.Position = 0;
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(outputStream))
    {
      rtfText = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
  }

  StoreInDatabase(rtfText);

  rtfText = LoadFromDatabase();

  // Convert the RTF string to a FlowDocument of an existing RichTextBox      
  var newTextRange = new TextRange(this.RichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, this.RichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
  using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rtfText)))
  {
    newTextRange.Load(inputStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
  }
}
```